# What is the default connection pool limit for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, connection, connection-pooling

I am using Mac OS and recently installed PostgreSQL using brew command.

Do you have any idea where in the configuration can I find the default connection pool limit?

I am providing read/write performance testing and I want to reassure that the database is not restricted by default.

Also, where can I access the configuration for setting up for example 100 connections.

Thanks!

Comment: [Postgres max connections](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=postgres+max+connections)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to clarify up front: postgresql does not have any built-in connection pooling. When you connect, the server forks a new process, when you disconnect, that process ends.

That said, brew tends to install things into a tree under `/usr/local`. For me, the database was created in `/usr/local/var/postgres`.

There are a few config files, but the important ones are `postgresql.conf` (most of the server configuration), and `pg_hba.conf` (where you define which hosts and users can connect to which databases).

In `postgresql.conf`, there is a configuration option, `max_connections`. That's most likely the configuration option you're looking for.

Comment: great, thank you for clearing it a little bit for me. Is there an option for increasing the performance locally?

Comment: Increasing performance? That's a very, very large topic, that depends almost entirely on things like: your hardware setup, your schema, and your usage patterns. If you find specific things that are slow, you can ask about those, but you should probably read: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions